# PCI-based VGA card works for installer but not installed OS

Tags: 16.04, server, display

I have what's almost definitely a niche problem. I purchased this [PCI-based VGA Controller](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0784MS8XJ) for a server I built. There are no drivers available and it came with no install media, but I figured I'd give it a try anyways. Without any additional work beyond plugging it in, the card gives output during post and the installer for ubuntu, however once the OS is loaded, my monitor gives the error "D-SUB OUT OF RANGE" and I no longer recieve output. I am still able to connect to the server through SSH, which I configure through the installer, but no direct access is possible, or at least doing so is completely blind.

The motherboard for this server has no onboard video and only a single PCI-E x16 slot, which is in use by a RAID controller, so as far as I can tell, this is pretty much my only option.

Any help appreciated, googling the error from my monitor yields very little.

Output of `sudo lshw` for the pci card in question:

```
*-pci:5
             description: PCI bridge
             product: 82801 PCI Bridge
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1e
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1e.0
             version: 90
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci subtractive_decode bus_master cap_list
             resources: ioport:b000(size=4096) memory:f9000000-faafffff
           *-display UNCLAIMED
                description: VGA compatible controller
                product: Rage XL PCI
                vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
                physical id: 7
                bus info: pci@0000:01:07.0
                version: 27
                width: 32 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list
                configuration: latency=64 mingnt=8
                resources: memory:f9000000-f9ffffff ioport:b000(size=256) memory:faadf000-faadffff memory:faae0000-faafffff
```

Comment: That card is so old that there's no support for it. If it doesn't work with the default open-source driver there's nothing you can do.

Comment: What guiverc said, although since it worked in the installer, you would think you'd at least have software rendering support. My brother has a Linux sever with some old as hell server board with weird on board graphics, but they work well enough through software rendering. I seem to remember a long time ago in Ubuntu 6 or something that for whatever reason I had to manually configure Xorg or something to use the proper PCI address for my graphics card, things worked a bit differently back then though. Still, it's something that you may want to check out.

Answer (score 0):

I have this card "working" in Ubuntu 20.04. It works if you boot into recovery mode, THEN continue the normal boot. Then it appears to use the llvmpipe driver. It is a bit wonky but it will at least run 1024x768. You also need to make sure VGA Pallet Snoop (I think that's what it's called) is enabled in the BIOS. I say "I think" because I do not want to reboot to check

It's a pain. I'm trying to find a way to force llvmpipe. ¯_(ツ)_/¯